# Pages: How to restore original lists styles

Tags: restore, pages, formatting, macos

I use Pages 5.5.x
The problem is that I have occasionally deleted "Lettered" list & bullets style.
Now I want to restore the default list of "list & bullets" styles for the document.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

### Pages '09 or 4.x

Here is a receipe working for `Pages '09`:

1. Open `Pages`, and choose the same template you want to restore defaults,
2. Select `File > Save` and save this empty file as `Desktop/Untitled.pages`
3. Open the document where styles were deleted, let's say `my_file.pages`
4. Select `Format > Import Styles...` and choose `Desktop/Untitled.pages`
5. Select the missing formats you want to recover, and to avoid duplicates, check the lower left box `Replace duplicates`, click `OK`
6. Remove `Desktop/Untitled.pages`

### Pages 5.x

Since Apple removed this function with `Pages 5` there are two workarounds:

**if** (you have `Pages '09` available)

**then** save your file under `Pages '09` format and apply the above receipe

**else** apply the following very **manual** (and stupid) receipe:

1. Open `Pages`, and choose the same template you want to restore defaults,
2. Create in this file a new dummy text line which will be used as an area to copy styles from
3. Select `File > Save` and save this empty file as `Desktop/Untitled.pages`: this will be the **source** document
4. Open the document where styles were deleted, let's say `my_file.pages`: this is your target document
5. Create at its end a new dummy text line which will be used as an area to use to paste styles
6. **For** (every style `xxx` to restore) **do**:

   1. In **source** document select the 1st dummy line and apply it the style `xxx`
   2. Select `Format > Copy Character Style` <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> if it is a character style, or `Format > Copy Paragraph Style` <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> if it is a list or paragraph style
   3. In **target** document, select the last dummy line
   4. Select `Format > Paste Character Style` or `Format > Paste Paragraph Style` <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>
7. Remove `Desktop/Untitled.pages`
8. In `my_file.pages` remove the last dummy line